# I want to print a pattern but when I am defining col variable within while it's working but when I defined it outside loop it's not giving proper otp

Tags: c++

I want to print a pattern but when I am defining col variable within while it's working but when I defined it outside my loop I'm not getting desired output.
Please explain.
I want this pattern

**1
23
456
78910**
**This code is giving desired output**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    
    cin>>n;
    int row=1,val=1;
    while (row<=n)
    {
        int col=1;
        while(col<=row){
            cout<<val;
            val=val+1;
            col=col+1;
            
        }
        cout<<endl;
        row=row+1;
    }
    
}
```

Proper output

[image: 1]

**But this code not**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    int col=1;
    cin>>n;
    int row=1,val=1;
    while (row<=n)
    {
        
        while(col<=row){
            cout<<val;
            val=val+1;
            col=col+1;
            
        }
        cout<<endl;
        row=row+1;
    }
    
}
```

Improper output

[image: 2]

Comment: What piece of code resets `col` back to `1`, after the entire rotation, of the inner loop, in the 2nd example? Once it becomes equal to `row + 1` - it stays equal to `row + 1`.

Comment: print the value of `col` in the inner loop to see the difference, or better use a debugger

Answer (score 0):

You missed to initialize `col` in the loop.

Try `col=1` before `while(col<=row)`